# Can't figure out how to check mask collision between two sprites

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision-detection, pygame-surface

I have two different sprites in the same group, variables 'player' and 'ground'. They both are separate classes, with a mask of their surface. This line is in both of their classes.

```
self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.surface)
```

The images used in their surfaces have 'convert_alpha()' used on them so part of them is transparent, and the mask should work on them. The ground is a few platforms, and I want to check for collision so I can keep the player on the ground, and have them fall when they are not on the non-transparent parts.

```
if pygame.sprite.collide_mask(player,ground):
        print("collision")
else:
        print("nope")
```

This prints "nope", even as the player sprite is falling over where the colored ground sprite pixels are. So the documentation for 'collide_mask()' says that it returns "NoneType" when there is no collision. So I tried this.

```
if pygame.sprite.collide_mask(player,ground)!= NoneType:
        print("collision")
```

This prints "collision" no matter where the player is(I have jumping, left, and right movements setup for the player). I asked a question about collision yesterday with no answer that helped. And I was told to condense my code submitted in the question so hopefully I explained this well enough without posting all 90 lines. I've checked a lot of other questions on here, and they all seem to do it a little different so I'm very confused (and fairly new).
Emphasis on both sprites being in the same group, I couldn't get spritecollide() to work because of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sprites do not only need the `mask` attribute, they also need the `rect` attribute. the `mask` defines the bitmask and `rect` specifies the posiotion of the sprite on the screen. See [`pygame.sprite.collide_mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask):

> Tests for collision between two sprites, by testing if their bitmasks overla. If the sprites have a **mask** attribute, it is used as the mask, otherwise a mask is created from the sprite's **image**. Sprites must have a **rect** attribute; the mask attribute is optional.

If sprites are used in `pygame.sprite.Group`s then each sprite should have `image` and `rect` attributes. [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The latter delegates to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) — you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group. [...]

The former uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects — you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

---

Minimal example

[image]

```py
import os, pygame
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

class SpriteObject(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
size = window.get_size()

object_surf = pygame.image.load('AirPlane.png').convert_alpha()
obstacle_surf = pygame.image.load('Rocket').convert_alpha()

moving_object = SpriteObject(0, 0, object_surf)
obstacle = SpriteObject(size[0] // 2, size[1] // 2, obstacle_surf)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([moving_object, obstacle])

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    moving_object.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    collide = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(moving_object, obstacle)
    
    window.fill((255, 0, 0) if collide else (0, 0, 64))
    all_sprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```